# How can I parse data using VBA-JSON with number range in URL?

Tags: json, excel, vba, web-scraping, xmlhttprequest

Need to use VBA-JSON to pull data from different URLs where the numbers in the URL change

I am collecting data from a crypto-game that I play. I am already able to parse data using the site's API for just my "mons". I am trying to to collect the same data for ALL of the mons in the game. The API lets you pull data for 99 mons at a time (caps at 99 at a time). There are approx. 48,000 mons in existence and that number continues to go up. Each mon has an ID number (1 being the first ever caught and n+1 for each one after that).

This is the link to access the data for mons 1-99: https://www.etheremon.com/api/monster/get_data?monster_ids=1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33,34,35,36,37,38,39,40,41,42,43,44,45,46,47,48,49,50,51,52,53,54,55,56,57,58,59,60,61,62,63,64,65,66,67,68,69,70,71,72,73,74,75,76,77,78,79,80,81,82,83,84,85,86,87,88,89,90,91,92,93,94,95,96,97,98,99

I need to pull data for mons 1-99, then 100-198, then 199-297 and so on all the way to 48000.

From each mon I want to collect the ID Number, "class_name", "total_level", "perfect_rate", "create_index" (which are all dicts) and most importantly I want the "total_battle_stats" (which is an array).

Here is the code I have for pulling all of those variables for just the mons in my inventory (it references a different link), but it already includes the arrangement of how I want it.

I just need those same variables but referencing a bunch of different links, not just one.

Option Explicit

Public Sub WriteOutBattleInfo()
    Dim headers(), r As Long, i As Long, json As Object, key As Variant, ws As Worksheet, battleStats As Object
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    headers = Array("Monster #", "Name", "Total Level", "Perfection", "Catch Number", "HP", "PA", "PD", "SA", "SD", "SPD")

```
With CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
    .Open "GET", "https://www.etheremon.com/api/user/get_my_monster?trainer_address=0x2Fef65e4D69a38bf0dd074079f367CDF176eC0De", False
    .Send
    Set json = JsonConverter.ParseJson(.ResponseText)("data")("monsters") 'dictionary of dictionaries
End With
r = 2
ws.Cells(1, 1).Resize(1, UBound(headers) + 1) = headers
For Each key In json.Keys
    With ws
        .Cells(r, 1) = key
        .Cells(r, 2) = json(key)("class_name")
        .Cells(r, 3) = json(key)("total_level")
        .Cells(r, 4) = json(key)("perfect_rate")
        .Cells(r, 5) = json(key)("create_index")
        Set battleStats = json(key)("total_battle_stats")

        For i = 1 To battleStats.Count
            .Cells(r, i + 5) = battleStats.Item(i)
        Next i
    End With
    r = r + 1
Next

Range(Selection, ActiveCell.SpecialCells(xlLastCell)).Select
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Sort.SortFields.Clear
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Sort.SortFields.Add2 key:=Range("C2:C110" _
    ), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlDescending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Sort
    .SetRange Range("A1:K110")
    .Header = xlYes
    .MatchCase = False
    .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
    .SortMethod = xlPinYin
    .Apply
End With
Selection.Columns.AutoFit
```

End Sub

I would like it to look exactly like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/7VmKS.jpg

But I want all of the Mons from ID 1 to 48000.

Comment: I can't see the expecfed result. Can you share with a different link sharing site?

Comment: https://postimg.cc/7fNfVD8x

let me know if that works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a function to increment the ids to concatenate onto a base url. The site throttles/blocks if you request too quickly/possibly too many times. Check the documentation for any advice on this.

I show how you could retrieve all. I include a test case for 1 to 5 requests (uncomment to get the full number of requests. Note: I give a line, for you to tweak, which allows for adding in a delay every x requests to try and avoid throttling/blocking. It seems likely the number is quite low before this happens.

Later on, you can consider moving this into a class to hold the xmlhttp object and provide it methods such as getItems. Example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52235053/6241235).

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub WriteOutBattleInfo()
    Const BASE_URL As String = " https://www.etheremon.com/api/monster/get_data?monster_ids="
    Const END_COUNT As Long = 48000
    Const BATCH_SIZE As Long = 99
    Dim numberOfRequests As Long, i As Long, j As Long, ids As String
    Dim headers(), r As Long, json As Object, key As Variant, ws As Worksheet, battleStats As Object

    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    headers = Array("Monster #", "Name", "Total Level", "Perfection", "Catch Number", "HP", "PA", "PD", "SA", "SD", "SPD")
    numberOfRequests = Application.WorksheetFunction.RoundDown(END_COUNT / BATCH_SIZE, 0)
    ids = "1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33,34,35,36,37,38,39,40,41,42,43,44,45,46,47,48,49,50,51,52,53,54,55,56,57,58,59,60,61,62,63,64,65,66,67,68,69,70,71,72,73,74,75,76,77,78,79,80,81,82,83,84,85,86,87,88,89,90,91,92,93,94,95,96,97,98,99"

    Dim results()
    ReDim results(1 To END_COUNT, 1 To 11)
    r = 1

    With CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
        For i = 1 To 5 'numberOfRequests + 1
            If i Mod 10 = 0 Then Application.Wait Now + TimeSerial(0, 0, 1)
            If i > 1 Then ids = IncrementIds(ids, BATCH_SIZE, END_COUNT)
            .Open "GET", BASE_URL & ids, False
            .send
            Set json = JsonConverter.ParseJson(.responseText)("data")

            For Each key In json.keys
                results(r, 1) = key
                results(r, 2) = json(key)("class_name")
                results(r, 3) = json(key)("total_level")
                results(r, 4) = json(key)("perfect_rate")
                results(r, 5) = json(key)("create_index")

                Set battleStats = json(key)("total_battle_stats")

                For j = 1 To battleStats.Count
                    results(r, j + 5) = battleStats.item(j)
                Next j
                r = r + 1
            Next
        Next
    End With

    ws.Cells(1, 1).Resize(1, UBound(headers) + 1) = headers
    ws.Cells(2, 1).Resize(UBound(results, 1), UBound(results, 2)) = results
End Sub

Public Function IncrementIds(ByVal ids As String, ByVal BATCH_SIZE As Long, ByVal END_COUNT) As String
    Dim i As Long, arrayIds() As String
    arrayIds = Split(ids, ",")
    For i = LBound(arrayIds) To UBound(arrayIds)
        If CLng(arrayIds(i)) + BATCH_SIZE <= END_COUNT Then
            arrayIds(i) = arrayIds(i) + BATCH_SIZE
        Else
            ReDim Preserve arrayIds(0 To i - 1)
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
    IncrementIds = Join(arrayIds, ",")      
End Function
```

Comment: Can't thank you enough man. You've helped me learn so much. Im trying right now with i = 1 To Number of Requests + 1. Im sure itll take a while, I keep losing connection - I think it's loading. Would it be easier if I just put in 1 to "the exact number"?

I'll play around with the delay first of course

Comment: No. I think the problem is the speed of the requests and likely also the number. I tried introducing waits every 100 requests, then every 25, then every 10 but still kept stalling though at every 10 Excel didn't freeze so it might have been processing slowly. You need to find that delicate balance of how many requests to make before wait is needed so the site doesn't think you are trying to spam it (see DDoS for example).  Bear in mind APIs often also have call rate limits. It requires 485 calls to get all your data.

Comment: Thanks again for all the help. Gonna do some research and look into the examples/references you gave. Ill let you know when I find what works.

Comment: Though slower if you don’t mind leaving to just continue churning through you might consider adding a long wait every 5 records or even switching to using selenium.

Comment: I'm sure other languages would be much easier. I'm just trying to get more comfortable using VBA. I'm very new to coding. Would you recommend learning a specific "base" language first like Python or C++ before I dive into VBA/Selenium. I want to learn as much as I possibly can.