# Store JSON results into an array excel vba

Tags: json, excel, vba

I have tried using API for get some information for Yahoo Finance
And this is the UDF that I created

```
Sub Test()
'1 >> High & 2 >> Close
MsgBox YahooHigh("GOOG", "2019-07-18", 1)
MsgBox YahooHigh("GOOG", "2019-07-18", 2)
End Sub

Function YahooHigh(sTicker As String, sDate As String, idx As Integer)
Dim json As Object

With CreateObject("WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1")
    .Open "GET", "https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=TIME_SERIES_DAILY&symbol=" & sTicker & "&outputsize=full&apikey=myapikey"
    .Send
    Set json = JsonConverter.ParseJson(.responseText)
End With

If idx = 1 Then
    YahooHigh = json("Time Series (Daily)")(sDate)("2. high")
ElseIf idx = 2 Then
    YahooHigh = json("Time Series (Daily)")(sDate)("4. close")
Else
    YahooHigh = Empty
End If
End Function
```

The UDF works fine but of course I will have to load the JSON result each time. As in my example, the UDF will run for twice the first for High value and the second for the Close value
Is there a way to store the json results into an array then instead of loading the json, the array is called. I thought of static but I am stuck at this

What I would like to do is to store all the dates in the json results for specific ticker (High value and Close value only) then to recall the desired value from the static array .. Any ideas?

Another variation:
I have tried using the HTML content and it works fine for me when using the link directly

```
Sub MyTest()
Dim html As Object, ele As Object

With CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP")
                 'https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/GOOG/history?period1=1325566800&period2=1325566800&interval=1d&filter=history&frequency=1d
    '.Open "GET", "https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/GOOG/history?period1=1325566800&period2=1325566800&interval=1d&filter=history&frequency=1d", False
    Dim sTicker As String
    sTicker = Sheets(1).Range("B1").Value   'GOOG

    Dim period1 As Long, period2 As Long
    period1 = ToUnix(Sheets(1).Range("B2").Value) '3 Jan 2012
    period2 = ToUnix(Sheets(1).Range("B3").Value) '3 Jan 2012

    .Open "GET", "https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/" & sTicker & "/history?period1=" & period1 & "&period2=" & period2 & "&interval=1d&filter=history&frequency=1d", False
    .Send

    If .Status <> 200 Then MsgBox "Problem" & vbNewLine & .Status & " - " & .StatusText: Exit Sub

    Set html = CreateObject("htmlfile")
    html.body.innerHTML = .responseText

    'WriteTxtFile html.body.innerHTML

    'Stop

    Set ele = html.getElementsByTagName("table")(0).getElementsByTagName("tr")(1)

    Dim tCell As Object
    Dim cnt As Long

    For Each tCell In ele.Children
        cnt = cnt + 1

        If cnt = 3 Then Debug.Print "High: " & tCell.innerText
        If cnt = 5 Then Debug.Print "Close: " & tCell.innerText
    Next tCell
End With
End Sub

Public Function ToUnix(dt) As Long
ToUnix = DateDiff("s", "1/1/1970", dt)
End Function
```

When using this line `.Open "GET", "https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/GOOG/history?period1=1325566800&period2=1325566800&interval=1d&filter=history&frequency=1d", False` it works fine and returns values from High and Close
But when trying to convert the dates from the worksheet to UNIX so as to use them in the link, it doesn't work
This is the problem for me now

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the initial problem has completely changed, with a different quote provider now being referenced.

Comment: This is the same target. Using API returns the results from Yahoo Finance.

Comment: Have a look at this [LINK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52234348/excel-vba-web-source-code-how-to-extract-multiple-fields-to-one-sheet/52235053?noredirect=1#comment100731606_52235053) to find the relationship

Comment: The relationship is not what you think it is.

Comment: I am sorry for that... I have no great idea. I was just trying to learn something new.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just have your function return the json object, then parse it in your sub.
The json object will contain all your data, and you can parse out what you want.

For example

In your function:

```
Function YahooHigh(sTicker As String) as object
Dim json As Object

With CreateObject("WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1")
    .Open "GET", "https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=TIME_SERIES_DAILY&symbol=" & sTicker & "&outputsize=full&apikey=myapikey"
    .Send
    Set YahooHigh = JsonConverter.ParseJson(.responseText)
End With
```

and in your Sub:

```
 Sub Test()
  Dim obj As Object
Set obj = YahooHigh("GOOG")

MsgBox obj("Time Series (Daily)")("2019-07-18")("2. high")
MsgBox obj("Time Series (Daily)")("2019-07-18")("4. close")

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I thought of that but I am not sure if this will be faster with searching for a lot of dates.

Comment: Another point when I tried `MsgBox obj("Time Series (Daily)")("2009-04-21")("2. high")` I got error, it seems that date is not in the JSON results. How can I fix that problem?

Comment: @yasserkhalil you'll need to take that up with alphavantage. That may be a limitation as to how far back the time series goes. Or maybe a change in your API called convention that.

Comment: You mean this is because free API ..? And If I bought API I could get more results?!

Comment: @QHarr this is the question that you told me to post as for the API restriction ..

Comment: @YasserKhalil So far as searching for a lot of dates, it'll certainly be faster than multiple calls.  Why would you think otherwise?

Comment: Thanks a lot. The problem is not with the search or calls. The problem is with the results of JSON that returned don't include all the dates. I have tried to read at the API website but I can't get a lot. And I am lost.

Comment: @YasserKhalil I suspect that the quotes of `GOOG` returned are probably only from around the time that Alphabet and Google merged.  On at least one historical site, the quotes did not go back that far.  But if you query for `MSFT`, you can go back quite a bit further -- 1998-01-02.  The GOOG quotes only go back to 2014-03-27

Comment: @YasserKhalil  AS I wrote above, you'll need to take it up with alphavantage about the historical quotes for GOOG, and why it only goes back to 2014.

Comment: @YasserKhalil and Google did do a funny kind of split on 2014-03-27 which resulted in different classes of stock. That is probably related to the historical quote length of GOOG

Comment: What about this [URL](https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/GOOG/history?period1=1325566800&period2=1325566800&interval=1d&filter=history&frequency=1d). The `GOOG` returns to 2012

Comment: @YasserKhalil What about it?  Your code is not accessing that URL.

Comment: @ Ron Rosenfeld I am talking about the results of JSON files that are returned from the API >> this date 2012 for this quote GOOG is not there. That's the point I am talking about

Comment: @ Ron Rosenfeld I have updated the main post with new code that I have a problem in. The problem is with the unix format

Comment: @YasserKhalil  And as I have written before, **this is an issue you will need to take up with the provider:**  alphavantage

Comment: @YasserKhalil Your new code is using an entirely different quote provider. Your new problem bears no relation to your original problem. You should be posting a new question.